# Python: Pandas shows NaN after passing dictionary to resample()

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nan, resampling

This is the head of a very large dataframe I have, whereby I have set `publish_datetime` as the index in Pandas:

```
                     sentiment_subjectivity  pos_sentiment_pol
publish_datetime
2016-12-18 16:56:01                  0.2500             0.2500
2016-12-21 16:56:05                  0.0000             0.0000
2016-12-21 16:56:08                  0.0000             0.0000
2016-12-21 16:56:08                  0.1027             0.1027
2016-12-21 16:56:13                  0.0000             0.0000
2016-12-21 16:56:17                  0.0000             0.0000
2016-12-21 16:56:18                  0.1027             0.1027
2016-12-21 16:56:19                  0.1027             0.1027
2016-12-21 16:56:22                  0.1027             0.1027
2016-12-21 16:56:23                  0.1027             0.1027
```

Now I want to resample it. I do it by passing a dictionary, because in the original dataframe I have a few more series. Nevertheless the result is the same:

```
df = df.resample('1min').apply({'pos_sentiment_pol':'sum'}).fillna('None')
```

This is what I get:

```
                    pos_sentiment_pol
publish_datetime
2016-12-18 16:56:00              0.25
2016-12-18 16:57:00              None
2016-12-18 16:58:00              None
2016-12-18 16:59:00              None
2016-12-18 17:00:00              None
2016-12-18 17:01:00              None
2016-12-18 17:02:00              None
2016-12-18 17:03:00              None
2016-12-18 17:04:00              None
2016-12-18 17:05:00              None
```

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element in your index is from 3 days prior.  It get's grouped by itself while everything afterwards gets grouped 3 days later or 4320 minutes later.

Either that's a typo or you wanted to see it grouped by hours and minutes regardless of the day.  If the latter is true, then

```
df.groupby([df.index.hour, df.index.minute])[['pos_sentiment_pol']].sum()

       pos_sentiment_pol
16 56             0.7635
```

If you change the value of that first index to be the same date as the rest then your code works fine

```
df.resample('1min').apply({'pos_sentiment_pol':'sum'}).fillna('None')

                     pos_sentiment_pol
publish_datetime                      
2016-12-21 16:56:00             0.7635
```

Comment: Thank you. This is a wrong number inside the data and I don't know how it has gotten there